# Set Transparent Window in AlertDialog box

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I want to set the Transparent window for the Default alertDialogbox. . .
How can i able to do it ??
My Alertbox is as like [this](http://www.android.pk/blog/easy-stocks/alertdialog-box-in-android/). Please refer it. .

Thanks in Advance. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is for activity
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android/3350428)

but still you can apply the same theme for dialog box too.

**Edit**

Create a class for the dialog as below

**CustDialog.java** :

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    Button button_home,button_cancel,button_resume;
    public GamePauseMenu(Context context) {
        super(context,R.style.Theme_Transparent);


    }
    public void show(int bg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.show();
        setContentView(R.layout.custdialog);
        button_resume = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        button_resume.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cancel();

    }


}
```

**custdialog.xml** in Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:background="@drawable/menu_home"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="auto" android:duplicateParentState="true"></Button>
    <Button android:background="@drawable/menu_next" android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/imageButton3" android:background="@drawable/menu_reset"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry Jana. . . but its not done. . Its not effect on the alertDialog box. . . Any other idea ??

Comment: See the Edited Question i hv set the link for the alertBox which i want transperent.

Comment: I know that is is possible by CustomDialogBox. But i want to do it in Default DialogBox. . .

Answer (score 0):

Hey... Now i m able to do it. . .
The code is as Follow. . .

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/MyOwnAlertbox</item></style>



<style name="MyOwnAlertbox" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog">
 <item name="android:fullDark">@color/light_blue</item>
 <item name="android:topDark">@color/black</item>
 <item name="android:centerDark">@color/red</item>
 <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/green</item>
 <item name="android:fullBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/blue</item>
```

Just add that Style in Your Manifest file. ..
as like. . .
`android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"`

Have Fun. . .