# android:how to change alertDilog Box Design by Style or Theme?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi Friends
     how to change alertDilog Box Design by Style or Theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Transparent** AlertDialog : [Set Transparent Window in AlertDialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800334/set-transperent-window-in-alertdialog-box)

You can look at Tutorial here :

http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=custom-alertdialog